# Remove wordpress admin user

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, admin

I have a client that has a wordpress website but i cannot do much since she did not have administrative rights. Is there a way to delete the old admin user or assign him a different role?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I assume you are logged in on phpMyAdmin.
Go to SQL and copy this code:

```
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DATABASE`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('2', 'USER_NAME', MD5('PASSWORD'), 'NICE NAME', 'EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM', 'URL', '2015-05-27 00:00:00', '', '0', 'DISPLAY NAME');


INSERT INTO `YOUR_DATABASE`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');


INSERT INTO `YOUR_DATABASE`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

You may need to change the values (uppercase) on the first line and the database names for all 3 lines. You will then create a new user which has admin rights.

If this doesn't work for you, simply increase the value of the ID, since it needs to be the last registered user.

Comment: Thanks for this information Reza but I just got a resolution to this and it works great! Here is the website with the intructions just in case anyone else needs it. http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED - Here is the website with the instructions just in case anyone else needs it. http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin/